# Operating System: Its beggining the my lecture but I couldn't write what was asked of me

Tags: binary, pthreads, mutex, deadlock, binary-semaphore

Write a program in which a global variable count is initialized to 0.
Then, create two threads.
In both threads, let there be a loop from 1 to N, and increment count in the loop.
Try to see if count is equal to 2N for various values of N (e.g. N=10,000).
For each N, you should run your program multiple times.

Comment on your results.

Comment: So what is the question? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far..